# Rockstar Social Club members with "Rockstar" as their country

Tags: rockstar-games-social-club

Is it possible to set "Rockstar" as your country, like [this user has](http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/member/KimFowleyJr/)? There doesn't appear to be any way to do it through your Profile Settings... but that doesn't mean it's not possible, as suggested by the linked profile.

Or does that logo mean it's an official Rockstar account?

Comment: just give it a try and you'll see if it works :P should take max of 20secs

Comment: @Nitro.de What are you talking about?

Comment: I can think of two reasons: 1) she's an employee of some sort, or 2) it may have been possible to enter plain text in your profile before, as opposed to the drop-down list they have now. It's no longer possible to do something like this now.

Comment: @IvoCoumans Yes. I'm looking for an answer.